# Mysql/PHP mysql update does not update database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET name='".$name."', 
             lastname='".$lname."', mail='".$email."', uab='".$company."', 
             mob='".$phone."', uabcode='".$companycode."', litnar='".$litnar."',
             address='".$address."', country='".$country."', city='".$city."' 
             where id ='".$userid."'") or die(mysql_error());
```

This is my query, all mysql_error() returns nothing.

Info does not update. $userid returns id .

Where could be problem?

Comment: Are you sure of the `$userid` value ? Does it exist in DB ?

Comment: yes echo $userid; returns user id.

Comment: echo your query and paste directly in to phpmyadmin it will work or not?

Comment: echo returns `UPDATE users SET name='Rytiskaka2', lastname='Taukkaka2', mail='rytis@vrv.lt', uab='imone2', mob='86333332', uabcode='kdos2', litnar='Yes', address='adresas2', country='salis2', city='miestas2' where id ='1'` when I post this to phpmyadmin it updates info. But script dosnt.

Comment: You appear wonderfully open to SQL Injection, you should be using parameterized queries.  Is `users.id` numeric or character type?  Do you have a row with that id?  Are you working under a transaction?

Comment: according to the MySQL documentation, the update query won't return something in the following cases:
- when using UPDATE, MySQL will not update columns where the new value is the same as the old value. This creates the possibility that mysql_affected_rows() may not actually equal the number of rows matched, only the number of rows that were literally affected by the query.
- if the `where` clause isn't met

Comment: Also, check if you're using multiple MySQL connections:
*Be aware that if you are using multiple MySQL connections you MUST support the link identifier to the mysql_error() function. Otherwise your error message will be blank.*

Comment: Did you try like that - 
$update = mysql_query(...);

Comment: There could also be a permission problem. Normally there is only a local user for phpmyadmin on the same host.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the concatenation and enclose the string variables in single quotes like this:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET name='$name', lastname='$lname', mail='$email', uab='$company', mob='$phone', uabcode='$companycode', litnar='$litnar', address='$address', country='$country', city='$city' where id ='$userid'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: There's no difference between this and what's currently there; this is interpolating variables into the query, as opposed to the original concatenating them together - the net result will be the same